# How to increment values using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

```
I have the following XML that has been generated from a Spreadsheet:

<DocumentElement>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>100</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_2>TWO</FIELD_2>
    <FIELD_3>110ST20</FIELD_3>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>100</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_2>TWO</FIELD_2>
    <FIELD_3>110ST20</FIELD_3>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>100</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_2>TWO</FIELD_2>
    <FIELD_3>11CST32</FIELD_3>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>100</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_2>TWO</FIELD_2>
    <FIELD_3>11CST32</FIELD_3>
  </Sheet1>
  <Sheet1>
    <FIELD_1>100</FIELD_1>
    <FIELD_2>TWO</FIELD_2>
    <FIELD_3>11CST32</FIELD_3>
  </Sheet1>
</DocumentElement>
```

Notice FIELD_3 in the first two  elements has the same number (110ST20) and FIELD_3 in the last 3  elements has the same number as well (11CST32). The number of times FIELD_3 may be repeated is unpredictable.

I want the number to be unique by adding a suffix of 01, 02, and so on - up to the number of times the number is repeated, so that the final result should look like this:

```
<details Number="100" Position="TWO" Value="110ST2001">
<details Number="100" Position="TWO" Value="110ST2002">
<details Number="100" Position="TWO" Value="11CST3201">
<details Number="100" Position="TWO" Value="11CST3202">
<details Number="100" Position="TWO" Value="11CST3203">
```

Here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="DocumentElement">

<DocumentElement>
  <xsl:for-each select ="/DocumentElement/Sheet1">
    <details>

        <xsl:attribute name="Number" >
          <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_1"/>
        </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:attribute name="Position" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_2"/>
      </xsl:attribute>

      <xsl:attribute name="Value" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_3"/>
      </xsl:attribute>          

    </details>
  </xsl:for-each>
</DocumentElement>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and my result is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <details Value="110ST20" Position="TWO" Number="100"/>
  <details Value="110ST20" Position="TWO" Number="100"/>
  <details Value="11CST32" Position="TWO" Number="100"/>
  <details Value="11CST32" Position="TWO" Number="100"/>
  <details Value="11CST32" Position="TWO" Number="100"/>
</DocumentElement>
```

How can I do this using xslt?

Thanks so much in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start by **grouping** your records, using the [Muenchian grouping method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Then you can number the members of each group sequentially, using their position within the group:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="sheet-by-f3" match="Sheet1" use="FIELD_3" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <DocumentElement>
        <xsl:for-each select="DocumentElement/Sheet1[count(. | key('sheet-by-f3', FIELD_3)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:for-each select="key('sheet-by-f3', FIELD_3)">
                <details Number="{FIELD_1}" Position="{FIELD_2}">   
                    <xsl:attribute name="Value" >
                        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD_3"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(position(), '00')"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>          
                </details>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </DocumentElement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```